Page 67 Lee smooth manifold - transition map of charts on tangent bundle clearly smooth?
Lee wrote the following on page 67 on his Introduction to Smooth Manifolds

The Tangent Bundle
Now suppose we are given two smooth charts $(U, \varphi)$ and $(V, \psi)$ for $M$, and let $\left(\pi^{-1}(U), \widetilde{\varphi}\right),\left(\pi^{-1}(V), \widetilde{\psi}\right)$ be the corresponding charts on $T M$. The sets
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \widetilde{\varphi}\left(\pi^{-1}(U) \cap \pi^{-1}(V)\right)=\varphi(U \cap V) \times \mathbb{R}^n \quad \text { and } \\
& \widetilde{\psi}\left(\pi^{-1}(U) \cap \pi^{-1}(V)\right)=\psi(U \cap V) \times \mathbb{R}^n
\end{aligned}
$$
are open in $\mathbb{R}^{2 n}$, and the transition map $\widetilde{\psi} \circ \widetilde{\varphi}^{-1}: \varphi(U \cap V) \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \psi(U \cap V) \times$ $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be written explicitly using (3.12) as
$$
\begin{aligned}
\tilde{\psi} & \circ \tilde{\varphi}^{-1}\left(x^1, \ldots, x^n, v^1, \ldots, v^n\right) \\
& =\left(\tilde{x}^1(x), \ldots, \widetilde{x}^n(x), \frac{\partial \widetilde{x}^1}{\partial x^j}(x) v^j, \ldots, \frac{\partial \widetilde{x}^n}{\partial x^j}(x) v^j\right) .
\end{aligned}
$$
This is clearly smooth.

For the last sentence, I don't understand why it's clearly smooth. In particular, why is $\frac{\partial \tilde x^{1}}{\partial x^{j}}(x)v^{j}$ smooth? Back to the definition, $\frac{ \partial }{ \partial x^{i} }(x)$ is a derivation that maps $C^{\infty}(U \cap V)$ to $\mathbb{R}$, where $\tilde x^{1} \in C^{\infty}(U \cap V)$, but why does $\frac{ \partial }{ \partial x^{i} }(x)$ varies smoothly in some sense with respect to $x$? I'm not sure if I'm thinking about this is the correct way.

The term
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \tilde x^j$$
is just the partial derivative of the smooth function $\tilde x^j$ with respect to $x^i$ (If you were to think of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ as a derivation, its action is exactly the partial derivative).
